# Sharing a Project: Windows Universal (Win 10) and WPF

Tags: wpf, windows, shared-libraries, win-universal-app

With the "Blank App (Universal Windows 8.1)" project template of Visual Studio 2013 a shared project was generated (containing a App.xaml file), that allowed you to target Windows 8.1 apps as well as a WPF applications.

By using the new "Blank App" project template of Visual Studio 2015 for building Windows 10 universal apps, no such shared project is generated anymore.

Does this mean, that Windows 10 universal app projects don't allow you to share code across the old platforms (WPF, Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone)?

Comment: Put the shared code in a [Portable Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: That is something different. I don't want to share just any code, but the startup project, which contains the App.xaml. This also means to have some compiler directives that you can use in your code to distinguish the platform.

Comment: Just checked the `Blank App (Universal Windows 8.1)` project template again. It does (of course) not target WPF, but only *Windows 8.1* and *Windows Phone 8.1* project. So it's unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: WPF is not targeted by default. But because the App.xaml is in a shared project, it is possible to add a WPF project. Here is an guidance: http://pmichaels.net/2014/11/07/creating-a-shared-project-in-wpf/

Comment: I think it's still better to use a PCL in this case.  A shared project will lead to many #if when your sharing cross platform

Comment: I think, a PCL won't allow you to share Xaml-files compared to the old shared project.